# How to get Facebook friends online status in iphone using Graph API.?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to get the list of all online friends using Graph API.

I am using the following..

```
[facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/friends?fields=id,name,online_presence" andDelegate:self];
```

but this gives me 0 results.

Thanks.

**EDIT:**

I already have the permissions for  doing this from FB.

Comment: that isn't a valid graph call

Comment: @PauldeLange can you help me out..? I am not sure how this Graph thing works... :P

Comment: Have you googled at all? [This](http://qpleple.com/fetch-online-friends-list-with-facebook-graph-api/) seems to be the only available way

Comment: No it isn't. Google tells you in at least 5 places that it is not possible with the Graph API. And the link I supplied tells you to use FQL, and yet your question shows a Graph call.

Comment: @PauldeLange  ok thanks... can FQl be used with iPhone..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the friends_online_presence permission correctly configured, try this:

```
NSString* method = @"fql.query";
NSString* fql = @"SELECT uid, online_presence FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend where uid1 = me())";
NSDictionary* params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject: fql forKey: @"query"];

[[self facebook] requestWithMethodName: method
                             andParams: [params mutableCopy]
                         andHttpMethod: @"GET"
                           andDelegate: delegate];
```

This will return you a list of friends with online presence: active, idle, offline or error.